# Why won't the engine start after replaced top gasket?

Tags: engine, starting, vw, diesel

I replaced the top gasket of my VW caddy 1.9 tdi and now it wont start. It says that the oil pressure is low but I have checked the oil and it is correct on the dip stick. The engine turns smooth and I have tried quick start bottle spray but still nothing. What could be the cause of engine failure?

Comment: Which gasket exactly?  Valve cover?  Make sure any wiring connections are connected, vacuum lines.

Comment: The top gasket and everything is completely connected

Comment: I would bet you didn't reconnect the oil pressure sending unit considering you are getting a low pressure signal. Not sure if this would keep the engine from running. I'm not sure if VW has the engine setup so it won't start if it doesn't get oil pressure, but it seems likely. (This is a SWAG, so take it for what it's worth.)

Comment: I have checked just now the oil pressure sending unit (sensor) is well plugged in

Comment: When you say "top gasket" are you referring to valve cover or head gasket? What? Please clarify.

Comment: If it tells you the "oil pressure is low" why are you checking the oil level, once you have enough then you need to make sure that oil is being pushed around the engine and creating enough pressure.

Comment: If you wish better help diagnosing your issue, you will need to be more descriptive of what gasket you mean, and tell us a bit more about your starting problem.  In general, using starting ether is not a good idea with diesels, and particularly the 1.9tdi.

Comment: Closing this as we seem to have lost the OP